# I want to draw multiple image, but it works only for last image

Tags: javascript

This function is make `"cards"` array in target object, and I added some codes to draw each element in `"cards"` array(see the mark : this part), but it doesn't work. How can i do?

```
var player = {
  cards = [];
};

function giveNCards(cardsArr, target, n) {
  target.cards = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    target.cards.push(cardsArr.pop());
  }
  ///////////   this part   //////////
  for (var i = 0; i < target.cards.length; i++) {
    var cardImage = new Image();
    cardImage.onload = (function(value) {
      return function() {
        ctx.drawImage(this, i * 100, 0);
      }
    })(i);

    cardImage.src = "./images/" + target.cards[i] + ".png"
  }
  //////////////////////////////////////////
  console.log(target.cards);
  return target.cards;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cardImage` is getting overwritten on each loop.

Variables (when defined with the 'var' keyword) are local to the function (function scope) and get 'hoisted' (moved to the top). What does that mean? Basically, your code will run like this:

```
function giveNCards(cardsArr, target, n) {
  var i, cardImage // <-- cardImage defined first here (hoisted) 

  target.cards = [];
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    target.cards.push(cardsArr.pop());
  }
  for (i = 0; i < target.cards.length; i++ ){
     cardImage = new Image();
     cardImage.onload = (function(value){
         return function(){
             ctx.drawImage(this, i * 100, 0);
         }
     })(i);

     cardImage.src = "./images/" + target.cards[i] + ".png"
  }
  console.log(target.cards);
  return target.cards;
}
```

The simplest fix for this (though there are others) is to move the contents of your second for loop to another function which will give it it's own scope.

```
function giveNCards(cardsArr, target, n) {
  var i

  target.cards = [];
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    target.cards.push(cardsArr.pop());
  }
  for (i = 0; i < target.cards.length; i++ ){
       renderCard(target, i)
  }
  console.log(target.cards);
  return target.cards;
}

function renderCard(target, i) {
     var cardImage = new Image();
     cardImage.onload = (function(value){
         return function(){
             ctx.drawImage(this, i * 100, 0);
         }
     })(i);

     cardImage.src = "./images/" + target.cards[i] + ".png"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention, the `i` value that you used inside the IFFE is from the global scope, therefore you always modifies the same value

```
var player = {
  cards = [];
};

function giveNCards(cardsArr, target, n) {
  target.cards = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    target.cards.push(cardsArr.pop());
  }
  ///////////   this part   //////////
  for ( var i = 0; i < target.cards.length; i++ ){
     var cardImage = new Image();
     cardImage.onload = (function(value){
         return function(){
             ctx.drawImage(this, value * 100, 0);
             // -------------------^
         }
     })(i);

     cardImage.src = "./images/" + target.cards[i] + ".png"
  }
  //////////////////////////////////////////
  console.log(target.cards);
  return target.cards;
}
```

Comment: Also syntax errors in the player declaration object.